# ¿Qué significa "corriente"?

Tags: selección-de-palabras, significado

Estaba trabajando en un centro de votación hace 2 días y ayudé a algunas personas que hablaban poco inglés a inscribirse como votantes.

Hablo español con nivel bajo avanzado y antes de empezar el trabajo, retoqué el vocabulario necesario en relación con la votación porque no quería equivocarme en medio de todo el estrés del día exigente. Además, entendía la importancia de facilitar al máximo el proceso de inscribirse y votar para los hispanohablantes.

Después de haber terminado el día, me di cuenta de que cada vez que les pedía a los votantes su identificación, les preguntaba si la dirección en la tarjeta era "corriente." Lo que quería decir era "actual." Lo extraño para mí era que nadie me corregía, así que me preguntaba si es correcto decir "la dirección corriente" con el significado de "la dirección donde vive actualmente."

Comment: _Current_ y _corriente_ son falsos cognados.

Comment: Is this address current? Esta es [tu/su] dirección actual? And yes,corriente and current are called false friends. current is actual in Spanish.

Comment: @Rodrigo Pues según el Diccionario Oxford y el DLE, no es cierta esa afirmación, ambas comparten la misma raíz latina.

Comment: @RubioRic Fue un comentario a la rápida, tienes razón.

Comment: @ROdrigo ¿Pueden ser dos palabras "falsos amigos" o "false cognates" aunque comparten la misma raíz etimológica? En la definición de "falsos amigos" del DLE citan "actualmente" y "actually" como ejemplos. Parece que son "cognados" según la definicion del DLE "emparentado morfológicamente" o por cognación, pero a la vez "falsos amigos", que en inglés siempre entendí come "false cognate". Así ¿sean "cognates" y también "false cognates"?

Comment: @cuevero Según entiendo, los _falsos amigos_ son palabras de dos idiomas que, como se parecen, uno cree equivocadamente que significan lo mismo. Y sería muy normal que la causa de esa confusión fuera porque son _cognados_ (tienen una historia común) o _falsos cognados_ (parecen tener una historia común, pero no).

Answer (score 8):

Aidan, gran labor la que estás realizando.

La acepción de **corriente** empleada en tu caso es perfectamente válida, tal y como recoge el DLE

> **corriente**
> 3. adj. Que está en uso en el momento presente o lo estaba en el momento de que se habla.

En España no es común emplear ese término dentro de ese contexto burocrático/administrativo. Como apuntas, suele usarse preferentemente **actual**.

Pero otra cosa es el uso que se haga en los Estados Unidos, donde la mayoría de latinos no proceden de España, allí quizás sea normal emplear **corriente** al identificarlo con el término inglés **current**. Deberías esperar algo más antes de aceptar una respuesta como válida en espera de que algún latino residente en EE. UU. nos dé su opinión.

Como curiosidad, no parece que se trate de [falsos cognados](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falso_cognado), ya que ambas palabras comparten su origen en la misma raíz latina.

Según el Diccionario Oxford

> [current](https://www.lexico.com/definition/current)
> Origin
>  Middle English (in the adjective sense ‘running, flowing’):
> from Old French corant ‘running’, from **courre** ‘run’, from Latin
> **curre**re ‘run’.

Según el DLE

> [corriente](https://dle.rae.es/corriente)
>  De *correr* y -nte; lat. **curre**ns, -entis.

Answer (score 4):

No sería la forma más normal de decir eso (normalmente dirías "¿Es la dirección actual/vigente?", "¿Es donde vive ahora?", "¿Está al día esta dirección?", o algo similar), pero por contexto cualquiera lo entiende.
Y técnicamente **es** uno de los significados de [corriente](https://dle.rae.es/corriente?m=form) (el 3), aunque se use más en el sentido de "común y corriente", o sea, algo normal, habitual, ordinario.